# Reduce the duration for long press on TouchableHighlight in react native

Tags: react-native

I have my touchable highlight with an onPress and an onLongPress. They both work as expected the problem is I want to reduce the duration the user has to hold the button before long press activates. Is there a way reduce how long the user has to hold the button for longpress?. Maybe some kind of overide?

```
<TouchableHighlight style={styles.square} onPress={this._onPressButton.bind(this,item)} onLongPress={this._onLongPressButton.bind(this,item)}>
   <View style={styles.button}>

   </View>
</TouchableHighlight>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There is a prop that you can pass to `TouchableHighlight`<sup>1</sup> called `delayLongPress`. You can read about it [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/touchablewithoutfeedback#delaylongpress).

Basically what it allows you to do is set, in milliseconds, how long until `onLongPress` is called.

From the documentation:

> Delay in ms, from onPressIn, before onLongPress is called.

In the example below the duration has been set to 500ms.

```
<TouchableHighlight
  style={styles.square}
  onPress={this._onPressButton.bind(this, item)}
  onLongPress={this._onLongPressButton.bind(this, item)}
  delayLongPress={500}
>
  <View style={styles.button}>

  </View>
</TouchableHighlight>
```

---

<sup>1</sup> Note that all `Touchables` have the props from `TouchableWithoutFeedback`. You can see the props for `TouchableHightlight`[here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/touchablehighlight)

Comment: Thanks that's exactly what I was looking for!